# How to update the array value and perform the same operation for the new values

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import math
t=int(input())
for i in range(0,t):
    n,x=map(int,input().split())
    arr=list(map(int,input().split()))[:n]
    if x>=n:
        for i in range(0,n):
            i=0
            j=1
            p=1
            p=int(p)
            print(p)
            arr[i]=arr[i]^(2**p)
            arr[j]=arr[j]^(2**p)
            
            i+=1
            j+=1
            print(arr)
```

My array value is not updating .for example if  n=4 x=4 and arr= [2,5,5,9],after first operation the array becomes [0, 7, 5, 9] and then i want to perform this operation for my new array which is [0,7,5,9] but it still performs on my previous array which [2,5,5,9] .I am new to python kindly help me. Thanks in adavnced.

Answer (score 2):

Your code with `n=4`, `x=4`, and `arr=[2,5,5,9]` executes the `for` loop 4 times and produces the output below (excluding printing `p`):

```py
[0, 7, 5, 9]
[2, 5, 5, 9]
[0, 7, 5, 9]
[2, 5, 5, 9]
```

The reason why it produces the output above is related to the XOR (`^`) operations you perform. Recall that `a ^ a = 0` and `a ^ 0 = a`. Now let's see what happens:

- In your `for` loop, you override `i` (you hardcode it to `i=0`) and you have `j=1` for all the iterations. This means you never modify `arr[2]` and `arr[3]`; this is why their values remain unchanged, `5` and `9`, respectively. (If you want to run the loop for `n` times, perhaps you want to consider using a `for` loop with another variable name, say, `k`, or a `while` loop).
- `arr[0]` happens to be `2` and `2**p` is also `2`, because `p=1` for all the iterations. So, `0` is the result of XOR-ing `2` with itself an even number of times, and `2` is the result of XOR-ing `2` with itself an odd number of times. For example, in the first iteration you actually do `2 ^ 2` and get `0`, in the second `2 ^ 2 ^ 2 = 2 ^ 0` and get `2`, and so on and so forth.
- `arr[1]` is not `2`, but more or less the same logic as above applies. In the first iteration, you have `5 ^ 2` (recall `p=1` so `2**p=2`) , which is `7`, in the second iteration you get back your original number `5` because `5 ^ 2 ^ 2 = 5 ^ 0`, and so on and so forth.